# EProf Erlang Profiling

Tags: erlang

I'm attempting to profile an Erlang application using eprof.  The results show that most time is spent in the dict module although the module I am most interested in profiling doesn't use dict directly, it's dependencies do which looks a bit like this:

```
A-- B - dict
 |- C - dict
```

A is the running process(a gen_server) and uses modules B and C which both use dict.  How can I tell which module is using dict the most?

Comment: Could you try tweaking one of the two modules to use orddict instead? If you try it each way (B/dict + C/orddict, then B/orddict + C/dict) you might have enough information to answer the question.

Comment: Interesting approach but I managed to work around this without changing code by using fprof which shows total time taken in a function (including it's calls) and other useful stuff like gc and process suspension.  Leaving this question open in case anyone has anythign else to add.

Comment: You can try to use [this escript](https://github.com/isacssouza/erlgrind) I wrote to convert fprof output into callgrind output and visualize it with kcachegrind or something similar

Comment: This sounds excellent, are you aware of any gnome based GUIs for this?

Comment: I don't know any gnome based alternative but I run kcachegrind on gnome just fine.

Answer (score 2):

To solve similar problem I've create converter from dbg trace format to callgrind format. It helped me to use kcachegrind as a visualizer of function call hierarchy with time cost information.

https://github.com/virtan/eep

Here is an example of view helping to find where the time is spent
https://raw.github.com/virtan/eep/master/doc/sshot6.png